# Getting MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server localhost:27017

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker

I want to establish a connection with my MongoDB database running in docker. Application seemingly starts without any problem but when I am trying to call any request like simple GET:

```
localhost:8082/devices
```

I am receiving two different errors depending on the configuration:

With properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.host=interviewTest
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.username=mongoadmin
spring.data.mongodb.password=secret
server.port=8082
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=interviewTest
```

I am receiving:

```
com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'command find requires authentication' on server localhost:27017
```

and for application.properties with different configuration:

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.username=mongoadmin
spring.data.mongodb.password=secret
server.port=8082
spring.data.mongodb.database=interviewTest
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongoadmin:secret@localhost:27017/interviewTest?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed.", "code" : 18, "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed" }
```

I created my MongoDB docker container like below:

```
docker run -p 27017-27019:27017-27019 
--name mongo 
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongoadmin 
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret 
-e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=interviewTest 
-d mongo
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.interview</groupId>
  <artifactId>exercise</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>device</name>
  <description>Spring boot with MongoDB</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.4.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mapstruct.processor.version>1.3.0.Final</mapstruct.processor.version>
    <mapstruct.version>1.3.0.Final</mapstruct.version>
    <spring.cloud.starter.netflix.hystrix.version>2.1.2.RELEASE</spring.cloud.starter.netflix.hystrix.version>
    <apache.common.lang.version>3.0</apache.common.lang.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
      <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
      <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>${apache.common.lang.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.cloud.starter.netflix.hystrix.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>

        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
          <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${mapstruct.processor.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>1.18.6</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>spring-boot-device-docker</finalName>
  </build>

</project>
```

In the docker hub documentation I found something like:

```
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME, MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
These variables, used in conjunction, create a new user and set that user's password. This user is created in the admin authentication database and given the role of root, which is a "superuser" role.
```

so if I got it properly there is no problem with the role of my basic user mongoadmin.

I was trying to combine multiple configuration options but it did not yield desirable effect. 
I will be grateful for advice on how to solve that problem with MongoDB configuration and connection establish.

Comment: You need to create manually user for `interviewTest` db, because running docker mongo, it will create user for `admin` db. Or, you can try [this](https://www.shapeblock.com/docker-mongodb/)

Comment: @Valijon thank you so much man, after huge struggle I was able to add a new user to a database and now everything is working fine. 
Bows to you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a solution with @Valijon support. Turns out that we cannot use ROOT_USERNAME to read out database. Our root user can be used to create new databases, collection, and new users. The solution is really easy. We should open our docker with the following command

```
docker exec -it mongo bash
```

and flag -it which mean that it will be an interactive terminal and after all, we will be able to talk with our container. 
After all, we are using mongo command like that to establish authentication with root admin credentials.

```
mongo -u mongoadmin
```

and in the next command line, we are passing password.

After all, we are using the command:

```
use interviewTest
```

to choose database in which one we will add a custom user.

Now we can type already prepared a script with a custom password, username, and roles:

```
db.createUser({user: "testUser", pwd: "pwd", roles : [{role: "readWrite", db: "interviewTest"}]});
```

Now everything works fine and we can use our database without authentication error.

Comment: You might need the role "dbOwner" in some cases. My spring boot app required this

Comment: I tried it and still getting the same error? :/

Comment: finally found the solution using [Can’t connect to mongod with the newly created user](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/cant-connect-to-mongod-with-the-newly-created-user/101465/2). 

don't use  `use interviewTest` to create new user in the first place. 
Instead try using the command  `use admin`.

It works !!!

Answer (score 4):

if you are using `admin` as user, then you do not need to give password, below properties works fine for me :

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.username=admin
spring.data.mongodb.database=mydb
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
mongodb://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<dbname>?authSource=admin
```

Answer (score 1):

this work for me:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.password=secret
```

Comment: `spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.username=mongoadmin
spring.data.mongodb.password=secret
server.port=8082

spring.data.mongodb.database=interviewTest

spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongoadmin:secret@localhost:27017/interviewTest?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
With application.properties configured like this I am still receiving error 18

Comment: please do not add `spring.data.mongodb.uri`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked option without URI and that yield the same error. Finally, turned out that the problem was with a user which we have to create because ROOT_USERNAME can be used only for managing database and create DB or other users with privileges. I added a user on my own after docker container was running and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a newborn MongoDB created trough Docker on Windows, the default user dont have privileges of remote connecting on the new DB, so you'll need to grant your user privilege by creating a new user with same credentials inside your db.

```
use YourDb

db.createUser({user: "testUser", pwd: "pwd", roles : [{role: "readWrite", db: "YourDB"}]})
```

PS1:the uri method on newer spring data doesnt work anymore.
PS2: you **mustn't** mix uri and single proprieties authentification